# Condition Expectation of Difference between Two Poisson processes

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

$P_t$ and $Q_t$ are poisson processes with rates $a$ and $b$.

How do I calculate $E[(P_t-Q_t)]^2|Q_t=m-P_t]$?

Comment: (1.) Please indicate what you tried. (2.) Any comment on the answers to your two previous questions?

Comment: Stefan gave you the **distribution** of $P_t$ conditioned on $P_t+Q_t=m$ hence you should be able to compute the mean of $(P_t-Q_t)^2=(2P_t-m)^2$ conditioned on $P_t+Q_t=m$, no? If $U$ is binomial $(m,p)$, what are $E[U]$ and $E[U^2]$?

Comment: Yep. Any obstacle remaining to reach a full proof? If not, I suggest that you write down your own solution, that you post it here, and, after a while, that you accept it.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, conditionally on $P_t+Q_t=m$, $(P_t-Q_t)^2=(2P_t-m)^2$ and the conditional distribution of $P_t$ is binomial $(m,p)$ with $p=at/(at+bt)=a/(a+b)$, hence
$$
E[(P_t-Q_t)^2\mid P_t+Q_t=m]=E[(2S_m-m)^2],
$$
where $S_m$ is binomial $(m,p)$. The decomposition $2S_m-m=2(S_m-mp)-(1-2p)m$ yields
$$
(2S_m-m)^2=4(S_m-mp)^2-4(1-2p)m(S_m-mp)+(1-2p)^2m^2.
$$
Thus,
$$
E[(2S_m-m)^2]=4E[(S_m-mp)^2]-4(1-2p)mE[S_m-mp]+(1-2p)^2m^2.
$$
Now, $E[S_m]=mp$ and $E[(S_m-mp)^2]=\mathrm{var}(S_m)=mp(1-p)$ hence
$$
E[(2S_m-m)^2]=4p(1-p)m+(1-2p)^2m^2.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
E[(P_t-Q_t)^2\mid P_t+Q_t]=4p(1-p)(P_t+Q_t)+(1-2p)^2(P_t+Q_t)^2.
$$

Comment: (1)-(2) For every $Z$ and $z$, $(Z-z)^2=(T-t)^2=T^2-2tT+t^2$ with $T=Z-E[Z]$ and $t=z-E[Z]$. Now, $E[T^2]=\mathrm{var}(Z)$ and $E[T]=0$ hence $E[(Z-z)^2]=E[T^2]+t^2=\mathrm{var}(Z)+(z-E[Z])^2$. Use this for $Z=2S_m$ and $z=m$, then $E[Z]=2mp$ and $\mathrm{var}(Z)=4mp(1-p)$.

Comment: ?? See last line of answer.

Comment: It does. But this is not the point. Please read.